# Gitlab Runner with docker-machine started failing without any changes

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-machine, apt-get

I have a Gitlab Runner set up with use docker-machine executor to spin up AWS EC2 instances on-demand.

This is my configuration file:

```
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 30

[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner-manager"
  limit = 3
  url = "https://git.domain.com"
  id = 18
  token = "12dcfvgbhnjfcvgbhjnk-9w2"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-01-12T06:08:06Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      BucketName = "domain-gitlab-runner-manager-cache"
      BucketLocation = "us-east-1"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 1
    IdleScaleFactor = 0.0
    IdleCountMin = 0
    IdleTime = 1800
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "gitlab-runner-autoscale-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
      "amazonec2-region=us-east-1",
      "amazonec2-vpc-id=vpc-123",
      "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-123",
      "amazonec2-iam-instance-profile=gitlab-manager-instance-profile",
      "amazonec2-request-spot-instance=true",
      "amazonec2-spot-price=0.50",
      "amazonec2-use-private-address=true",
      "amazonec2-private-address-only=true",
      "amazonec2-tags=product,gitlab-runner,environment,shared",
      "amazonec2-security-group=gitlab-runner-manager-sg",
      "amazonec2-instance-type=t3.large",
      "amazonec2-root-size=100",
    ]
  [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
    Periods = ["* * 1-17 * * mon-fri *"]
    IdleCount = 1
    IdleTime = 3600
    Timezone = "UTC"
  [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
    Periods = ["* * * * * sat,sun *"]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleTime = 3600
    Timezone = "UTC"
```

My servers recently started eroring out with the below snippet from logs:

```
Feb 14 08:25:21 ip-10-10-0-251.ec2.internal gitlab-runner[2138]: ERROR: Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: Error running "sudo apt-get update": ssh command error:  driver=amazonec2 name=runner-nxw1xfxl-gitlab-runner-autoscale-1676363082-24ebaeda operation=create
Feb 14 08:25:21 ip-10-10-0-251.ec2.internal gitlab-runner[2138]: ERROR: command : sudo apt-get update                driver=amazonec2 name=runner-nxw1xfxl-gitlab-runner-autoscale-1676363082-24ebaeda operation=create
Feb 14 08:25:21 ip-10-10-0-251.ec2.internal gitlab-runner[2138]: ERROR: err     : exit status 100                    driver=amazonec2 name=runner-nxw1xfxl-gitlab-runner-autoscale-1676363082-24ebaeda operation=create
Feb 14 08:25:21 ip-10-10-0-251.ec2.internal gitlab-runner[2138]: ERROR: output  : Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]  driver=amazonec2 name=runner-nxw1xfxl-gitlab-runner-autoscale-1676363082-24ebaeda operation=create
Feb 14 08:25:21 ip-10-10-0-251.ec2.internal gitlab-runner[2138]: ERROR: Reading package lists...                     driver=amazonec2 name=runner-nxw1xfxl-gitlab-runner-autoscale-1676363082-24ebaeda operation=create
Feb 14 08:25:21 ip-10-10-0-251.ec2.internal gitlab-runner[2138]: ERROR: W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease into data and signature failed  driver=amazonec2 name=runner-nxw1xfxl-gitlab-runner-autoscale-1676363082-24ebaeda operation=create
Feb 14 08:25:21 ip-10-10-0-251.ec2.internal gitlab-runner[2138]: ERROR: E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.  driver=amazonec2 name=runner-nxw1xfxl-gitlab-runner-autoscale-1676363082-24ebaeda operation=create
```

The error message is quite straightforward - whereas the **sudo apt-get update** fails when the EC2 instance is being spun up.

My question now is - how do I sign it to be able to work? I don't even understand what this signing is tbh.

PS: I am not sure if the Gitlab runner part is relavant to the issue but I thought I would share on how I spin up the AWS EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, just added the latest Ubuntu AMI and it works flawlessly. Assuming the default AMI Gitlab uses had some issues. Syntax looks like this (under **MachineOptions**)

amazonec2-ami=AMI_ID